# How to happend an action when selecting item in jcombo box

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jcombobox

I'm searching old invoices using customer's name. Usually I select item in jcombo box and press the button to happen the action. It is working properly. I want to know is there any way we can load the action when I selecting the item from jcombo box. [image]

Also I want to know how to refresh the jtable. Please be kind to help me.. thank you.

This is the source code I write to button's action.

```
           private void btnSearchCustomerActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                  
      public void loadOldInvoiceByCustomer(JComboBox comboCustomer, JTable jtable2) {

    try {
        ResultSet rs1 = db.getData("SELECT cuid FROM customer WHERE cuname='" + comboCustomer.getSelectedItem().toString().trim() + "' ");
        while (rs1.next()) {
            try {
                ResultSet rs2 = db.getData("SELECT DISTINCT inid FROM invoice WHERE cuid=' " + rs1.getInt("cuid") + " ' ");
               while (rs2.next()) {
                    ResultSet rs3 = db.getData("SELECT DISTINCT isdate FROM  indetails WHERE inid='" + rs2.getInt("inid") + "'");
                    try {
                        while (rs3.next()) {
                            Vector v = new Vector();
                            DefaultTableModel df = (DefaultTableModel) jtable2.getModel();
                            v.add(rs2.getInt("inid"));
                            v.add(comboCustomer.getSelectedItem().toString());
                            v.add(rs3.getString("isdate"));
                            df.addRow(v);
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {

                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, this.getClass().getName() + " " + "rs3" + e);
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, this.getClass().getName() + " " + "rs2" + e);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, this.getClass().getName() + " " + "rs1" + e);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Some code would be helpful. Also, tried SelectionListener?

Comment: no. but shouldn't we do it right click jcombo box==> event==> select an event ? Isn't it the way?

Comment: What do you mean by _"refresh the table"_? What causes it to refresh and what does a refresh consist of? More details please.

Comment: I want to clear the table before load the data to table. usually we use            DefaultTableModel df = (DefaultTableModel) jTable2.getModel();
        int rowCount = df.getRowCount(); }
        for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
            df.removeRow(0);

Comment: You can use `model.setRowCount(0);` to clear it

Comment: And what do you mean _"load the action"_ You need to be more specific in exactly what you want to acheive. You can't expect us to guess what your program does, especially _without_ any code. You've asked many questions here. You should already know how to ask a proper question.

Comment: @peeskillet please read below description I did to  giovybus's question

Comment: So you want to add just the customer name from the combobox to table or is there more data for each row you want to add?

Comment: @peeskillet I add my code too..

Comment: The does nothing for me because I don't understand wha your problem is. You have to keep in mind you're the only one whe knows what your program does. If you don't explain what its supposed to do in detail and explain what isnt working, no on is going to be able to help you. You're only going to get a bunch of guesses. _"any way we can load the action"_ makes absoultely  no sense in the little context you are giving us

Comment: dear peeskillet I added my code. Please take a look at it. When I'm loading my invoice details to the table I select the name from jcombobox and press the button. The source code of action of the button is I given. And I want to do the same action only selecting the data from jcombo box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for `JComboBox` you must call the actionListener's method like this:

```
combo.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "selected: " + combo.getItemAt(combo.getSelectedIndex()));
            }

        });
```

Comment: i=I used that action event. In it I load the customer names from database to that jcombo box. Thing is I want to refresh the table and load customer's invoice data to table I given before. I already coded to take customer's invoice data. I donno which method I should code to load that data to table when I select the item without clicking button..

Comment: you can try, to delete all items of the table, and load the new data

Comment: `for(int i=0; i<countRows; i++){
   tableModel.removeRow(0);
  }` for remove all items

Comment: `for(int i=0; i<yourDAtaSize; i++){
    tableModel.addRow(yourData());
   }` for load the new data

Comment: can you please tell me what is your idea of yourDAtaSize. I uploaded my button's source code too.

Comment: my `yourDataSize` is your `while(rs3.next()){ ... } `

Answer (score 0):

You can add ItemListener  when Combobox item changed the event is called

```
JCombobox.addItemListener(new ItemListener(){
     public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e){
         System.out.println(e.getItem());
     }
});
```